# Printer crashed into model

Tags: z-axis, calibration, print-failure, anycubic-i3-mega

So first of all I want to say, that I'm fairly new to 3D printing. I'm currently calibrating different things because I've got a little problem with rough walls. The last thing I did was increase the belt tension for X and Y a little bit. I now wanted to print a calibration cube with these new settings. Therefore I sliced the cube with Cura and started the print. Around 20 minutes into the print, I heard this weird sound and immediately stopped the print. Somehow the printer crashed into the printed cube. The adhesion to the plate was a little too good so the head got completely stuck.

I moved the head up and removed the print. It's pretty obvious looking at it, that for some weird reason the printer dropped the nozzle around 5 mm down. I tested all motors and axis, but everything seems to work alright. So the next thing I checked, was the G-code. I measured the height of my cube and found Z to be around 13.2 mm when it crashed. I don't know much about G-code, but I checked every Z movement between 12.7-13.5 mm and didn't find any value to be out of this range.

I have no idea what to check next. But I guess there has to be a major problem with my printer if this just happens. Maybe some of you have more ideas about what to check.

Printer: Anycubic i3 Mega S
Firmware: Standard
Slicer: Cura 4.13

[image: Half printed model with burn marks]

[image: Another view of a half printed model with burn marks]

Answer (score 3):

It seems, after checking the G-code file thoroughly, there was indeed an error in the G-code, that I didn’t find when I checked it the first time.

The Z-Axis suddenly moves from `Z13.3` to `Z9.175`. I have no idea how something like this can happen.

Comment: bad G-code can happen if you mistakenly overwrite only arts of a file or if you append G-code to other code messing up Z. usually it is manual interference or some massive error in the slicer